# Using Classy for iOS, how do i add a shadow to a UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm using `Classy` **(www.classy.as)** for my new iOS app and I am trying to figure out how to add a shadow to a UILabel using the stylesheet only. The documentation doesn't seem to mention this. I know how to add a shadow manually using the CALayer technique and I'm aware there are subclassed labels that do this, but I want a pure Classy solution as we want to keep all the styling in the stylesheet for easy switching.

Here is my label:

```
UILabel.small
font $font-light 17
text-color: $text-color-light
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for something similar to the following:

```
UILabel.small
  font $font-light 17
  text-color: $text-color-light
  layer @
    shadow-color   black
    shadow-offset  9,3
    shadow-opacity 0.6
    shadow-radius  4
```

Take a look at the documentation it covers most topics, http://classy.as/properties/

Comment: I somehow missed this in the docs :( I got it working but right after committing to git and running it on the device it stopped working on both the simulator and the device. I tried resetting to before the commit, cleaning, deleting derived data, resetting simulator and just adding the above code again. It's just stopped working for no reason. I also tried adding a border via the layer property and that works, so the selector is fine. It's just ignoring the shadow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Classy, but I know that you can apply the properties shadowColor and shadowOffset to a UILabel.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/shadowColor

Classy may offer a way to access this property *(maybe **shadow-color: $foo?**)*